# Change the background of first view controller with switch on second

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am making an app with 2 view controllers and I want to be able to change the background and other features of the first view controller with a switch on the second view controller. I am pretty new to programming and was wondering how it was done. I have managed to change the elements on the 2nd view controller but can't figure out how to change them on the first. This is the code I have for the second view controller. What would I need to change so that the first view controller background changes as well?

```
// set function for changing to dark mode
func updateMySwitchState(){
    if darkModeSwitch.isOn {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        removeAds.textColor = UIColor.white
        aboutText.textColor = UIColor.white
        about.textColor = UIColor.white
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "backinvert-40"), for: .normal)

    }
    else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        removeAds.textColor = UIColor.black
        aboutText.textColor = UIColor.black
        about.textColor = UIColor.black
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back-40"), for: .normal)
}
}
```

I pass the above function into the IBAction for the switch

Comment: You can use `delegate` to change things in first viewController from second viewController

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

You can use this, to set background color to all your viewcontrollers

To set global color for UILabel text you can this

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in couple of ways.

```
1.you can use Delegation.
2.you can use Observer.
3.you can use Unwind segue.
4.you can also use callback method.
```